# Compile OpenSSL MinGw on windows - make[1]: *** [Makefile:2800: crypto/dso/dso_win32.o] Error 1

Tags: makefile, build, compiler-errors, openssl, mingw

I'm trying to build OpenSSL with MinGw 32 bits on windows, therefore
I installed mingw and MSYS as asked, I then installed Perl on MSYS, I had download OpenSSL-1.1.1 from the official webiste which I extracted to C:/openssl with

> -tar xf

Then, in MSYS, I did  :

> -perl Configure mingw shared --prefix=/c/openssl
>
> -make depend
>
> -make

And at this point, It's giving me [tons of errors](https://pastebin.com/29VxuYYR):

```
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2772: crypto/dso/dso_win32.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/openssl'
make: *** [Makefile:171: all] Error 2
```

I looked around on stackoverflow and google for answers but I couldn't find any answer on my problem. What did I do wrong ? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found the answer, I was using the wrong gcc (not the mingw one) because of the export PATH of MSYS2.

I did

> which gcc

and it gave me the wrong path so doing

> export PATH="/path to msys/msys2/mingw32/bin:$PATH"

did the trick.

If anyone is having the same issue, hope this helps.